# Flutter Adaptive Banner size doesn't get updated when phone is rotated

Tags: android, flutter, orientation, banner

I'm trying to implement an Adaptive Banner in Flutter but the banner size doesn't get updated when a phone is rotated from landscape to portrait and vs visa. I don't know if this is a bug or something that I did wrong.

This is what it looks like in landscape mode.

[image]

This is what it looks like in portrait mode.

[image]

I'm using the latest `google_mobile_ads`

This is Ad load function

```
Future<void> _loadAd() async {
    final AnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize? size = await AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.truncate());
     if (size == null) {
      print('Unable to get height of anchored banner.');
      return;
    }
    _anchoredAdaptiveAd = BannerAd(
     
      adUnitId: AdHelper.bannerAdUnitId,
      size: size,
      request: AdRequest(),
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          //  print('$ad loaded: ${ad.responseInfo}');
          _isBannerAdReady = true;
          setState(() {
             _anchoredAdaptiveAd = ad as BannerAd;
            _isBannerAdReady = true;
          });
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
          print('Anchored adaptive banner failedToLoad: $error');
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
    );
    return _anchoredAdaptiveAd!.load();
  }
```

I tried to reload in the build function but it doesn't re-calculate the size. Any work around to this problem?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    if (porientation == null) {
      porientation = orientation;
     } else {
      if (porientation != orientation) { 
//reload ad when orientation is changed
        reloadAd();
        porientation = orientation;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. The place holder ads are not dynamic and mostly the ads are cut off. If you notice the test tag is in the center. Be rest assured that the real ads will be placed properly

Comment: Thanks. It's good to know that the real ads will be placed properly. I'll register a device to test by using real ads.

Comment: Also do not test real ads. If you see test ads you are good to go.